# null being assigned as object in tail recursive function

Tags: javascript, null, tail-recursion, typeof

I have a tail recursive function whose purpose is to find any `number` in any number of nested `objects` and simply run the `toFixed()` on it.

The function formatData() works by looping through the `object`, testing to see what type of value is the current iteration is on, performing a function(toFixed()) on said iteration and saving it in a new object or do nothing and just saving the value as is. The end result will be a an identical object but with any long decimal place numbers trimmed to two decimal places.

During testing I've found that if there is a `null` value in the `object` at any level, it is first saved as `null` but later ends up being an `object`. I'm aware that in JS `null` is considered of type `object` and the `typeof` keyword will show this.

Here is a codepen of the problem: https://codepen.io/Danny_Wobble/pen/YzqMzxw
Please note that the third console entry shows the value being correctly assigned/saved as `null`. Later on as described it ends up as an `object`.

Function:

```
function formatData(data) {
    const formattedData = {}
    for (const key in data) {
        if (data[key] === null) formattedData[key] = null
        // if (data[key] === null) formattedData[key] = 'null' // have tried saving as diff val, didn't work
        if (data[key] === false) formattedData[key] = false
        if (typeof data[key] === 'number') formattedData[key] = data[key].toFixed(2)
        if (typeof data[key] === 'object') formattedData[key] = formatData(data[key]) // tail recursion
    }
    return formattedData
}
```

Given:

```
const data = {
     status: false,
     survey: {
         2018: 3.4288,
         2019: 3.47701,
         2020: null,
     },
     benchmarks: {
         company: 3.455,
         industry: 3.5,
         portfolio: 3.4,
     },
}
const formattedData = formatData(data)
```

Expectation (formattedData):

```
{
     "status": false,
     "survey": {
         "2018": "3.43",
         "2019": "3.48",
         "2020": null,
     },
     "benchmarks": {
         "company": "3.50",
         "industry": "3.50",
         "portfolio": "3.40",
     },
}
```

Actual result (formattedData):

```
{
  "status": false,
  "survey": {
    "2018": "3.43",
    "2019": "3.48",
    "2020": {} // this should be `null`
  },
  "benchmarks": {
    "company": "3.50",
    "industry": "3.50",
    "portfolio": "3.40"
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure on`null`, possibly `undefined`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude `null` values from the object check.

```
if (data[key] && typeof data[key] === 'object')
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You could change the logic for checking only the values for different processing, like numbers and objects and `continue` or just assign the given value to the new object.

```js
function formatData(data) {
    const formattedData = {}
    for (const key in data) {
        if (typeof data[key] === 'number') {
            formattedData[key] = data[key].toFixed(2)
            continue;
        }
        if (data[key] && typeof data[key] === 'object') {
            formattedData[key] = formatData(data[key]);
            continue;
        }
        formattedData[key] = data[key];
    }
    return formattedData;
}

const
    data = {
        status: false,
        survey: {
            2018: 3.4288,
            2019: 3.47701,
            2020: null
        },
        benchmarks: {
            company: 3.455,
            industry: 3.5,
            portfolio: 3.4
        }
    },
    formattedData = formatData(data);

console.log(formattedData);
```

Comment: Is equality on null invalid?

Comment: the problem is, `null` is an object.

Comment: Ok so it never equals