# Search bar filtering

Tags: javascript, html, search, filter, searchbar

I made a library archive site, When the user searches for books by title in the search bar it will compare that value to my available list of books in my ls and display it as a list under the bar when a match is found. There are 2 problems.

1. My displayed list items duplicate every time there is a match for the value being inputted, and even does so when backspaced
2. On the note of the backspace, I want all of the items to not be displayed when there is nothing in the search bar which you can see i attempted through an if statement

```
/////////////////////Search Bar//////////////////////////
const input = document.querySelector("#listSearch").addEventListener("keyup",function(e){

  let value = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
 console.log(value.length)

 if (localStorage.getItem('books') === null) {
  books = [];
} else {
  books = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'));
}

  document.querySelectorAll("#myList li").forEach(function(li){
    for(i=0;i<books.length;i++){
      console.log(books[i])

      li = document.createElement('li');
      li.className = "list-group-item"
      li.textContent = `${books[i].title}`
      document.querySelector('#myList').appendChild(li);
      console.log(li)
    
       
       if(value.length === 0){
         li.style.display = 'none'
          console.log(value);
       }
      else if(li.textContent.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) != -1){
               li.style.display = 'block'
               console.log(li)
     }

    }

})

})
```

HTML

```
  <div class="search-bar">
              <input class="form-control" id="listSearch" type="text" placeholder="Search Archives">
              <!-- <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button> -->
            
            <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
              <li class="list-group-item">item</li>
             
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Comment: Just looked at a post where `null` is an object and thus the equality comparison is always false. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64090580/null-being-assigned-as-object-in-tail-recursive-function

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelector('#listSearch').addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(e.target.value, 'i');

  let [books, booksString] = [[], ''];
  if ((booksString = localStorage.getItem('books')) !== null) {
    books = JSON.parse(booksString);
  }

  const myList = document.getElementById('myList');
  myList.innerHTML = '';

  books
    .filter((book) => regex.test(book.title))
    .forEach((book) => {
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      [li.className, li.textContent] = ['list-group-item', book.title];
      myList.appendChild(li);
    });
});
```

And I highly suggest you add a debouncer. You don't want to do this on every keyup. Maybe wait for 600ms after the input change.

Comment: this error pops up when i enter the code; filter.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: myList.appendChild is not a function
    at filter.js:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (filter.js:16)

Comment: Check my updated answer. I have used wrong query selector. Now should be fine.